# How to disable Synaptics touchpad accidental gestures?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, synaptics-touchpad

I have a Synaptics touchpad on a PCSpecialist laptop. It is not compatible with Windows Precision Driver.

When I do very small light flicks with one finger in any direction, the cursor registers and move visually but then it 'resets' and move back to its original starting position.

This is very annoying since I like to to little fine movements that I previously could with the MacBook touchpad.

Does anyone know how to disable this feature?

PalmCheck is all the way to 'Minimum';
Touch Sensitivity is at 'Light Touch';
and every other options under 'Pointing' is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, it seems this is impossible if you have 'Tapping' enabled.